Ubuntu Studio 24.04 Wifi Networks Show but Cannot Connect | Stuck at "Configuring Interface"
I am brand new to Ubuntu as I just switched from windows. I have installed Ubuntu Studio 24.04. After installing I added a PCI Wifi Network Adapter (Not USB). I can connect to the internet no problem with a LAN cable.
After disconnecting the LAN cable I attempted to connect via wifi. I cannot. I see many networks in the network manager, and enter the password and everything for my home wifi, but the wifi gets stuck on "Configuring Interface" for a minute, and then disconnects.
After disconnecting I receive the "Wireless Interface (wlp7s0) The wifi network cannot be found". I also receive a "Connection Deactivated"
I have tried connecting to other wifi networks and the same thing happens. I also went into BIOS and enabled network upon boot. Still the same issue.
My Wifi card is ASUS PCE-AC56 Wireless-AC1300 PCI-E Adapter. Ubuntu shows it as BCM4352. I have installed the driver for it. When I go to "Additional Drivers" it says it is using "dkms source for the Broadcom STA wireless driver from broadcom-sta-dkms.
Any ideas on where I should go from here?

What is the exact model of the WiFi card you installed? Did you install a driver for it? Please edit the question and add this critical info.

My Wifi card is ASUS PCE-AC56 Wireless-AC1300 PCI-E Adapter. Ubuntu shows it as BCM4352. I have installed the driver for it. When I go to "Additional Drivers" it says it is using "dkms source for the Broadcom STA wireless driver from broadcom-sta-dkm
